# Number of balanced bracket sequences with given prefix and suffix

Tags: combinatorics, catalan-numbers

I've been trying to solve the following problem:

Find the number of balanced bracket sequences of size $N+M+K$ which start with a prefix of $N$ continuous opening brackets and end with a suffix of $M$ continuous closing brackets (there can be any sequence of brackets of length $K$ as long as whole sequence is balanced).

I thought that maybe there is some correlation between this problem and Dyck paths/Catalan numbers but even after doing some research, I couldn't find any paper describing it in detail. Is it an already known (and well-studied) problem? Is there any formula for that? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These correspond to sort of possibly raised double-sided ballot paths, a rather straightforward variant of ballot paths, and that may be the reason you don't see many papers describing it. You might want to check some papers on *tunnels* in Dyck paths to see if you find more useful information.

Suppose at first that none of the initial $N$ brackets match any of the final $M$ brackets.

Think of this as Dyck paths of length $N+M+K$ starting with $N$ up-steps and ending at height $M$ down-steps. Remove the initial $N$ up-steps and final $M$ down-steps, and shine two lights horizontally from $-\infty$ and $\infty$ onto your path. This highlights $N$ down-steps and $M$ up-steps. This yields a unique decomposition of your remaining path $P$ of length $K$ starting at height $N$, ending at height $M$, and never going below the $x$-axis, as
$$
D=P_Nd\dots P_2dP_1dRuQ_1uQ_2\dots uQ_M,
$$
where the $u$'s and the $d$'s are the highlighted steps (they correspond to the brackets matching the initial $N$ opening brackets and final $M$ closing brackets), and $P_1,\dots,P_N, Q_1,\dots,Q_M,R$ are some Dyck paths of total semilength $\frac{K-N-M}{2}$.

Thus, the generating function for our paths over all $K$ is
$$
x^{N+M}C(x)^{N+M+1},
$$
where $C(x)$ is the Catalan generating function, and we want the coefficient at $x^{N+M+\frac{K-N-M}{2}}=x^{\frac{K+N+M}{2}}$ in its power series, which is
\begin{multline*}
[x^\frac{K+N+M}{2}]x^{N+M}C(x)^{N+M+1}=[x^{\frac{K-N-M}{2}}]C(x)^{N+M+1}\\
=\frac{N+M+1}{\frac{K+N+M}{2}+1}\binom{K}{\frac{K+N+M}{2}}=\binom{K}{\frac{K+N+M}{2}}-\binom{K}{\frac{K+N+M}{2}+1},
\end{multline*}
where the last equality follows e.g. from applying Lagrange inversion.

Now suppose exactly $L$ of the $N$ initial steps match $L$ of $M$ final steps, where $L\le\min(M,N)$. Then remove these $L$ pairs of matching brackets to arrive at the case considered above, but with $N\gets N-L$ and $M\gets M-L$, so our count in that case is
$$
\frac{N+M+1-2L}{\frac{K+N+M}{2}+1-L}\binom{K}{\frac{K+N+M}{2}-L}=\binom{K}{\frac{K+N+M}{2}-L}-\binom{K}{\frac{K+N+M}{2}+1-L}.
$$

Thus, our total count is
$$
\begin{split}
&\sum_{L=0}^{\min(M,N)}{\left(\binom{K}{\frac{K+N+M}{2}-L}-\binom{K}{\frac{K+N+M}{2}+1-L}\right)}\\
&=\binom{K}{\frac{K+N+M}{2}-\min(M,N)}-\binom{K}{\frac{K+N+M}{2}+1}.
\end{split}
$$
However, note that $\frac{K+N+M}{2}-\min(M,N)\in\left\{\frac{K-N+M}{2},\frac{K+N-M}{2}\right\}$ and these values sum to $K$, so it does not matter which one is used at the bottom of the binomial coefficient. Thus, our answer is
$$
\binom{K}{\frac{K-N+M}{2}}-\binom{K}{\frac{K+N+M}{2}+1}.
$$

Answer (score 4):

Let $T = \frac{K+M+N}2$. Your expression has $T$ open brackets and $T$ closed brackets, corresponding to lattice walks in the plane from $(0,0)$ to $(T,T)$ which stay at or above the line $y=x$. Since you are requiring the path to start with $N$ open brackets and $M$ closed brackets, you can only freely choose the path from $(0,N)$ to $(T-M,T)$. The total number of paths, ignoring the $y=x$ restriction, is
$$
\binom{(T-M)+(T-N)}{T-N}=\binom{K}{(K+M-N)/2}.
$$
We must now subtract the bad paths from $(0,N)$ to $(T-M,T)$ which at some point hit the line $y=x-1$. If we reflect such a bad path at the first point it hits $y=x-1$, the reflected path will instead end at $(T+1,T-M-1)$ instead of $(T-M,T)$. Since reflection is a bijection, the number of bad paths is equal to the total number of paths from $(0,N)$ to $(T+1,T-M-1)$, which is$$\binom{(T+1)+(T-M-N-1)}{T+1}=\binom{K}{(K+M+N)/2+1}.$$ Therefore, the number of good paths is
$$
\boxed{\binom{K}{(K+M-N)/2}-\binom{K}{(K+M+N)/2+1}.}
$$